# How to merge two or more asscoiative array keys in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Please i need to merge this:

```
arrays 
    { "Components": { "ID": 119, "Name": "Fire", }
        , "Company": { "ID": 6, "Name": "Leadw", }
        , "InsuranceType": { "ID": 3, "Name": "Motor" }
        , "ID": 119
        , "Percentage": 5 
    }
    , { "Components": { "ID": 120, "Name": "Flood", }
        , "Company": { "ID": 6, "Name": "Leadw", }
        , "InsuranceType": { "ID": 3, "Name": "Motor" }
        , "ID": 120
        , "Percentage": 2 }
    , { "Components": { "ID": 121, "Name": "Theft", }
       , "Company": { "ID": 6, "Name": "Leadw", }
       , "InsuranceType": { "ID": 3, "Name": "Motor" }
       , "ID": 121
       , "Percentage": 4 
    }
```

Comment: please format your post. If that's JSON, it is not valid at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you brought only one array ...
If you imagine that there are two such arrays ...
Then like this:

```js
var arrays1 = [{
            "Components": {
                       "ID": 119,
                       "Name":"Fire",
            },
            "Company": {
                        "ID": 6,
                        "Name": "Leadw",
            },
            "InsuranceType": {
                        "ID": 3,
                        "Name": "Motor"
            },
            "ID": 119,
            "Percentage": 5
            },

            {
            "Components": {
                           "ID": 120,
                           "Name":"Flood",
            },
            "Company": {
                           "ID": 6,
                           "Name":"Leadw",
            },
            "InsuranceType": {
                           "ID": 3,
                           "Name": "Motor"
            },
            "ID": 120,
            "Percentage": 2
            },

            {
            "Components": {
                           "ID": 121,
                           "Name": "Theft",
            },
            "Company": {
                           "ID": 6,
                           "Name": "Leadw",
            },
            "InsuranceType": {
                           "ID": 3,
                           "Name": "Motor"
            },
            "ID": 121,
            "Percentage": 4
            }];

var arrays2 = [{
            "Components": {
                       "ID": 125,
                       "Name":"Fire1",
            },
            "Company": {
                        "ID": 6,
                        "Name": "Leadw1",
            },
            "InsuranceType": {
                        "ID": 3,
                        "Name": "Motor1"
            },
            "ID": 125,
            "Percentage": 7
            },

            {
            "Components": {
                           "ID": 128,
                           "Name":"Flood",
            },
            "Company": {
                           "ID": 6,
                           "Name":"Leadw",
            },
            "InsuranceType": {
                           "ID": 3,
                           "Name": "Moto5"
            },
            "ID": 128,
            "Percentage": 2
            }];





         var merge_arr=[];

         for(var key1 in arrays1){
          merge_arr.push(arrays1[key1]);
         }
         for(var key2 in arrays2){
          merge_arr.push(arrays2[key2]);
         }
        //for test
        for(var key_ma in merge_arr){
           console.log(merge_arr[key_ma], 'Components ID =>'+merge_arr[key_ma].Components.ID);
        }
```